# Applying a different click handler to an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok so i have this relevant code in jQuery:

```
myself.insertAfter('.archive:last');
```

'myself' is just a variable containing a selector. So I remove the unnecessary class from it and apply the new one: 'archive'. However, when i click the newly inserted element, the actions i want to run after clicking an element with a class of 'archive' on it, does not happen. Now i know why this is happening, i just dont know how to solve it. I need to unbind the original click handler and apply a new one, but how!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stab in the dark here but I'm assuming your click handler uses

```
$("some selector").click(function(e) { ... });
```

Use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead

```
$("parent selector").on("click", "some selector", function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: +1 - Hah, you beat me by seconds.  That was my "stab in the dark too."

Answer (score 0):

Use the `unbind()` method:

```
$('.archive').unbind('click').on('click',function(){
    // Unbind the current click events and add a new one
});
```

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: FYI unbind has been deprecated in favor of .off() in the latest jQuery.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you for catching that;
`$('.archive').off('click','**').on('click',function(){ /* Function stuff */ });`